# What is the mistake in this code that it shows value error : substring not found in this python 3 code

Tags: python

# This program is to accept a name and a number as many times as user wants and check weather the inputed name exsists or not
Input:

```
#no. Of times=3
Mosh 94884331
Kelly 73773871
Jonny 73773737
Mosh 
John
Jonny
```

Output:

```
Mosh=94884331
Not found
Jonny=73773737
```

Code:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    name_ph=input()
    nauser=input()
    l=len(name_ph)
    name=name_ph[:name_ph.index(' ')]
    ph=name_ph[name_ph.index(' ')+1:l]
if nauser==name:
    print(name+'='+ph)
else:
    print('not exists')
```

Comment: The listed output says `Not found`, but the code prints `not exists`.  You aren't showing us the actual output (or code).

Comment: Could you provide reproducible code? I tried to run your program but it crashes when I enter a name and/or number and hangs when I enter in a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accepting your input correctly. Take this example:

```
name_ph=input()
nauser=input()
# Mosh 94884331
# Kelly 73773871
```

In the first iteration, it'll store these two lines. I am sure that is not what you want.

Ideally, you want to store the name and number and then search by name. This is a perfect example to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
n = int(input())
# empty dictionary
d= {}
print("Space separated name and numbers")
for i in range(n):
    s = input().split()
    # store the name as the key and number as the value
    d[s[0]] = s[1]

# store the names in a list to search
print("Enter names to find number")
find_list = []
for i in range(n):
  find_list.append(input())

# check for the names in the dictionary
for i in find_list:
  if i in d:
    print(i + " " + d.get(i))
  else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank u Harshal Parekh